# ActionMailer custom mail sender

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer to notify users when they are mentioned on an web application that I'm working on, I want the mail sender to look something like `User Name (via MyApp) <user@mail.com>`

I tried to do something like the code below after reading the documentation but I still can't get it to work.

```
email_with_name = "#{@user.name} (via MyApp) <#{@user.email}>"
mail(to: email_with_name, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
```

Comment: This looks like it does in the RoR guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-with-name

Comment: I read the guide and tried that example @benjaminjosephw but when I view the email sender it does not appear anywhere

Comment: Does the email sends fine with just `to: "John Smith <#{@user.email}>"` or even `to: "#{@user.email}"`? If not do you have any output you can include?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I use. I found it somewhere on the internet, but can't remember where or else i'd give credit where it's due:

```
class ApplicantMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  require 'mail'
  address = Mail::Address.new "name@example.com" # ex: "john@example.com"
  address.display_name = "Name" # ex: "John Doe"
  # Set the From or Reply-To header to the following:
  address.format # returns "John Doe <john@example.com>"
  default from: address

  def send(to)
    @to = to
    mail(:subject => "my method", :to => @to)
  end
end
```